# Correct way to get user details from django User

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm Building project for practice and i have a product and i want to show to everyone all the names of users that selling this product.
I've set the user field as ForeignKey of User in models,but I'm getting in the response object only the id of the user without anything else. What is the correct way to access the user name?

The model of the product sellers:

```
class ProductSeller(models.Model):
   product_id=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default = None)
   user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   condition = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=condition_choices)
   asked_price=models.IntegerField()
   image=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
```

The view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getSellersById(request,pk):
   sellers=ProductSeller.objects.filter(product_id=pk)
   seralizer=SellersSerializer(sellers,many=True)
   return Response(seralizer.data)
```

The response object:

```
    {
    "id": 2,
    "condition": "Almost new",
    "asked_price": 50,
    "image": "image.jpg",
    "product_id": 8,
    "user": 1
},
```

The wanted result:

```
     {
    "id": 2,
    "condition": "Almost new",
    "asked_price": 50,
    "image": "image.jpg",
    "product_id": 8,
    "user": 1,
    "seller_name":"John"

},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to `Product` model:

```
Product(...):
    ...
    def get_all_users_selling(self):
        return User.objects.filter(productseller_set__product_id=self)
```

After that add it to the serializer's response:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getSellersById(request,pk):
   sellers=ProductSeller.objects.filter(product_id=pk)
   seralizer=SellersSerializer(sellers,many=True)
   for seller in seralizer.data:
        seller["all_users"] = [user.username for user in Product.objects.get(seller.get("product_id")).get_all_users_selling()]
   return Response(seralizer.data)
```

Also, don't use `_id` in the end of `ForeignKey` field variable, it's confusing, because Django creates column with `_id` suffix, so it becomes `something_id_id`.

Comment: It will give me all the users that sell the product for each seller object.So in every seller object i will get property of all the users that sell the product. What i want is for each product the name of only the user that selling it . It feels like it's supposed to be really easy but i'm missing a step

Comment: @Michael so this was confusing: "i want to show to everyone all the names of users that selling this product" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the sellerSerializer class a method that give me the seller name:

```
class SellersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   seller_name=serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
   class Meta:
       model=ProductSeller
       fields='__all__'
   def get_seller_name(self,obj):
       return str(obj)
```